# Is this PHP contact form secure?

Tags: php

Can you please tell me whether the following PHP contact form is secure? (It gets used with AJAX.)

```
<?php
$email_to = "myaddress@email.com";

$email_subject = "My subject";

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$error_message = "";

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return filter_var(str_replace($bad, "", $string), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
}


$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";


// create email headers

$headers = "From: myaddress@email.com\r\n".
           "Reply-To: myaddress@email.com\r\n".
           "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's secure -- but I'm not certain it's what you want.

Assuming you have control over the `$email_to`, `$email_subject`, and `$headers` variables (as it appears you do in the code), you're definitely targeting the variables that could make you vulnerable to script injection -- `$name`, `$email`, and `$message`.

That said, it appears that the `filter_var` command (which, I will confess, I've not used before) will strip, rather than convert, text that doesn't correspond to its filter. And since you are applying the `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` filter to things that are not, in fact, e-mail (i.e., name and message), you may lose content that you want.

I think the `htmlentities` command is a better fit for what you need.

Comment: Actually, neither `clean_string` nor `htmlspecialchars` is necessary as all user input goes into the message body which is *text/plain* by default.